# StreamLit App demanding each feature from classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, web-applications, streamlit

I am deploying my machine learning model on a web app using the Streamlit API. I am giving 6 features to the app from my dataset, but my dataset has around 66 features after one hot encoding. So i make an app front end which is fine but when ever i press predict button after entering values of my 6 features it says **"X has 6 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 66 features as input".**

So how can I solve this issue? I don't want to enter 66 features.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For us to help you, we need to know more about what you're doing.  Do you have code you can show us?  SO is about programming.  High-level machine learning questions are not in scope for this site.  If you don't have code to show, your question would be better suited for [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) ... or maybe [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You fitted a classifier with 66 features, you need to provide the same 66 features, you cannot provide less and expect the classifier to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's potentially two ways to solve your problem based on the information you've provided:

1. It seems like you used some sort of preprocessors/transformers during feature preprocessing that turned the 6 features into 66 features which was then passed into your model. If that is the case, you can create a [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) object that combines your preprocessor and your model into a single pipeline. That way, when you pass in 6 features into your pipeline object, it will transform them into 66 features and then pass it into your model which should prevent this error from showing up.
2. In the case that you aren't actually using a preprocessor and only want to enter 6 out of 66 features, you can create an array of length 66, and set all values to None (this is okay since tree models know how to handle Nones), and then just replace parts of the array that correspond to the 6 features that you have. This should prevent errors as well.

Hope this helps!